# How to clear textarea with button?

Tags: java, swing

This is my first time with Java. How do I clear the text in a textarea with button? My code for entering etc. is like this:

```
        enter = new JButton("Enter");
        enter.setActionCommand("enter");
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        delete = new JButton("Clear");
        delete.setActionCommand("delete");
//      delete.addActionListener(questionarea.setText(""));
               
        //Create and set JPanels
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        deletePanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        deletePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        
        //Area for user input
        questionarea = new JTextArea();
        questionarea.setFont(new Font("Silom", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        questionarea.setEditable(false);
        
        //Adding components to panel
        topPanel.add(questionarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottomPanel.add(enter);
        deletePanel.add(delete);
        
        //Adding panels to JFrame
        add(timerPanel);
        add(bottomPanel); 
        add(deletePanel);
```

I used the textarea here where I enter numbers to answer a simple addition or subtraction question:

```
    public void generateRandomProblem()
    {       
    if(prob == 0)
    {
            opert = '+';
            Answer = A + B;
    }   
        else
        {
            opert = '-';
            Answer = A - B;
        }
               
        String q = "" + A + " " + opert + " " + B + " = ";
        questionarea.setText(q);
    }
```

Comment: put listener on button, check the button id which want should clear then call setText("") or clearText or some equivalent method on the component

Comment: You have to up vote the answer if it is helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put `setText("")` inside button listener...

```
delete = new JButton("Clear");
delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        questionarea.setText("");
    }
});
```